# C# Retrieve MySQLDateTime default value from DataSet

Tags: c#, mysql, datetime

I have a `DateTime` field with a value of the mysql default value('0000-00-00 00:00:00').

I am using `MySqlDataAdapter` to fill a `DataSet` and than Iterate the rows and to convert the row['dateColum'] I use Convert.ToDateTime(object).

When I set the connection string to `Convert Zero Datetime=True` than MySqlDataAdapter.Fill gets an exception `Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM>`

But when I remove `Convert Zero Datetime=True` from the connection string, I get an exception `Unable to convert MySQL date/time value to System.DateTime`

Why the hell such simple thing is so hard?

**EDIT: an example**

```
try
{
    using (MySqlConnection SQLCon = new MySqlConnection(ConnStrUtils.GetConnectionStr(dbName)))
    {
        using (MySqlCommand Cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, SQLCon))
        {
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            foreach (var param in parameters)
            {
                Cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
            }

            using (MySqlDataAdapter DA = new MySqlDataAdapter(Cmd))
            {
                DataSet innerDs = new DataSet();
                await DA.FillAsync(innerDs);
                return innerDs;
            }
        }
    }
}

catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

My connection string: `datasource=***;port=**;user id=root; password=***; database=indicators; pooling=true; CharSet=utf8; Allow User Variables=True; Convert Zero Datetime=True; Allow Zero Datetime=True; default command timeout=720`

The db value of 1 column is `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, and in the fillAsync function I get: `Type of value has a mismatch with column typeCouldn't store <1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM> in p_startTime Column.  Expected type is MySqlDateTime.`

Comment: It would be better to see a [MCVE]

Comment: @Soner Gönül, added the code which runs the stored procedure(which receives an dataset)